# Why my WebStorm keep showing Vue TypeScript 4.5.4, though I'm using React TypeScript

Tags: webstorm

I'm not so sure why my WebStorm keep showing Vue-TypeScript although I'm using React TypeScript.

Is this the reason for the typescript-auto-import preferences not working ?

[image: WebStorm]

Comment: do you have `vue` in your project dependencies? Vue typescript service is normally only enables in vue.js apps

Answer (score 3):

Please uncheck Vue.js plugin. I hope it would be helpful.